# Using ternary operator on Object?.property to check if object and object property is defined

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

If I want to check an object or an objects property is not undefined, I've done in following methods

- `if(object == null)`
- `if(object === undefined)`
- `if(object != null)`
- `if(object !== undefined)`
- `if(object && object.hasOwnProperty('foo'))`

I keep coming across this kind of syntax in code bases `object?.foo`

Does this mean that, it check if the object is not undefined and then checks if the foo property is also not undefined?

Thanks!

Comment: `object?.foo` is a short form for `object == null ? null : object.foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct. This is called Optional Chaining

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling I was struggling to search with the right term.